# Error in "Desktop.getDesktop().open( "d:\\Output.csv" );"

Tags: java, multithreading, csv, external

In my program I am making a `.csv` file and then before exiting I want the `.csv` file to open up. I tried to use this code: `Desktop.getDesktop().open( "d:\\Output.csv" );` but it gives an error saying: `cannot find symbol. Symbol: variable Desktop`

(I am doing this inside a button, before it exits the program)
Code:

```
System.out.println("Done!");
    Done.setText("Done!");
    Desktop.getDesktop().open( "d:\\Output.csv" );



    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }                
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Desktop.getDesktop().open( ”d:\\Output.csv“ );` by `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("d:\\Output.csv"));`

Answer (score 1):

Check if this isn' t just a missing import of java.awt.Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method, for e.g `fileUpload`

```
public fileUpload() {
        File file = new File("c:\\file_name.csv");
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

then, try out once using this method and implement it on your code. Now see what's going on!

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }                
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: @developerknownasInsar Kindly update the answer according to upd1

Comment: The 2nd code block is the exact same... where are you calling fileupload? I think it is a typo. is it? and as far as the 1st block is concerned, if i copy paste it into my file i get errors,

Comment: here `upload` is a method, you says you are getting an error, you can't upload file `.csv`, i guess, if you made a method to upload you can easily invoke everywhere in your program where you want to embed it, just through Object, i guess that's a best idea, that's why i'm telling you here to use `fileupload` method. ;)

Comment: See i don't know what you are talking about, ii am not uploading anything neither have a made a method myself. I have just made a simple program from Netbeans. Check upd3

Comment: Listen, don't depend on `Netbeans`, it's just an IDE which works as editor, just go for concepts, you are implying to upload your file, so i'm telling you to use a `Method` `(in c language says FUNCTION)`. try out once my program, if it's uploading your file, then go for method which you can invoke easily by calling it everywhere where you want to implement it :) ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47085/discussion-between-daksh-shah-and-developer-known-as-insane)